# Disabling scrolling acceleration on Max OS X

Tags: macos, mouse, scrolling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you disable mouse scroll wheel acceleration in Mac OS?](https://superuser.com/questions/200660/how-do-you-disable-mouse-scroll-wheel-acceleration-in-mac-os)

Using a fairly generic gaming mouse (no Mac drivers available) on Leopard, I've noticed that the faster I scroll, the more distance I travel per "tick". I find this quite annoying, yet there doesn't appear to be a way to control the mouse scroll acceleration.

On Windows and Linux, I'm used to having the mouse scroll three lines per tick.
Can something be done about this?

Comment: A very similar problem, mouse pointer acceleration, has been [discussed at great length](http://superuser.com/questions/218314/disabling-mouse-acceleration-in-mac-os-x), with the apparent conclusion that there's no built in way, but there are some hacky ways to do it. See if any of the info there helps you.

Comment: @nhinkle: I did. No luck so far.

Comment: My sense is that there's probably no way to fix it.

Comment: oh totally, it's good that you asked, I'm just saying it's not likely to get solved, at least currently.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it would answer your question. There's a "thing" call "inertia" scrolling in Mac OS X, which enables you to scroll faster without having to scroll too much with the mouse. Please consider change the setting to **"without inertia"** and see if that's what you need.

[image]

P.S: Sorry I don't have Leopard machine available and my screenshot is for Mountain Lion. Please tell me if this doesn't work with Leopard. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: I only have that inertia option for my trackpad. Doesn't it just disable inertial scrolling? (Where views keep scrolling after you flick a multi-touch surface.)

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure. For me, I have both 2 options "with inertia" and "without inertia".